# How to update the state of array when onclick in the image(icon) without refresh page in react js

Tags: reactjs

i am fetching some array of items with the expample url('https://www.getadata.com/items') and using authentication fetching some more wishes with the example url('https://www.getadata.com/wishes'), i had mixing both array data with matching UID, displaying in the ui....if the true value showing the radio checked icon or false to radio unchecked icon , now i want to post the true or false values of wish with onclick on the radio button..i am maintaining the like , after onclick the icon...

**i can post successfully...but i cannot see in the UI....after refreshing page then i can see updated array in the UI....how to update the array without refreshing page and see updated array in the UI**

Please help me on this....

code sand box link : https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-push-the-array-of-objects-data-into-another-array-with-matching-uid-forked-dcov3?file=/demo.js:0-3585

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import RadioButtonCheckedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RadioButtonChecked";
import RadioButtonUncheckedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/RadioButtonUnchecked";
import axios from "axios";
class Wish extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { uid: "1001", item: "iPhone" },
        { uid: "1002", item: "iPad" },
        { uid: "1003", item: "iTab" },
        { uid: "1004", item: "iTelevision" }
      ],
      wishes: [
        { uid: "1001", wish: true },
        { uid: "1002", wish: null },
        { uid: "1003", wish: true },
        { uid: "1004", wish: null }
      ],
        UserToken: sessionStorage.getItem('UserToken'),
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://www.getadata.com/items")
      .then((resposne) => {
        this.setState({
          items: resposne.data.items
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    if (this.state.UserToken) {
      axios
        .get("https://www.getadata.com/wishes")
        .then((resposne) => {
          this.setState({
            wishes: resposne.data.wishes
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
  clickedIcon = (item) => {
    if (this.state.UserToken) {
      fetch("https://www.getadata.com/wishes", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Token ${this.state.UserToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          courses: [
            {
              uid: item.uid,
              wish: !item.wish
            }
          ]
        })
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    const itemsObj = this.state.items.reduce((itemsObj, item) => {
      return {
        ...itemsObj,
        [item.uid]: item
      };
    }, {});
    const mergedObj = this.state.wishes.reduce((mergedObj, { uid, wish }) => {
      return {
        ...mergedObj,
        [uid]: {
          ...mergedObj[uid],
          wish
        }
      };
    }, itemsObj);

    return (
      <div>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>UID</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">Item</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">Wish</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {Object.values(mergedObj).map((item) => (
                <TableRow key={item.name}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {item.uid}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{item.item}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell
                    onClick={() => this.clickedIcon(item)}
                    align="left"
                  >
                    {item.wish === true ? (
                      <RadioButtonCheckedIcon />
                    ) : (
                      <RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />
                    )}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Wish;
```

Comment: No `.then` from the `fetch` to handle the response and update state? The same call is made on component mount, so this is likely why you see the data upon page reload. I don't have a token so I can't get the `fetch("https://www.getadata.com/wishes", ...)` to work though.

Comment: if your free can we chat on these...please

Comment: Sure, lets chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221363/chat-with-manoharpamishetty